# Can you get a similarity percentage between items using ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, field, similarity, items

I'm considering using ElasticSearch to hold, search and get statistics on data but I'm not sure if what I would like to do is possible or not.

The main goal would be to get the percentage of similarity between items stored in the database. For example, given the two following identical objects:

`{'Item A': [{'name':'bob', 'age':20}]}, {'Item B': [{'name':'bob', 'age':20}]}`

I would like to compute something like this:

`Item ID1 | Item ID2 | Matching percentage
 Item A   | Item B   | 100`

Does ElasticSearch allow for such computations, looking for similarity percentage between fields of two given objects ? If not what would you suggest ?

Thank you for your time,

Oliver